# Can I improve this tree using linked list implementation code by adding others data in the node eg.the student ID instead of only the name? and how?

Tags: c

```c
/* demonstrating transversal of binary trees */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct BinTreeNode
{
    char *data;
    struct BinTreeNode *left;
    struct BinTreeNode *right;
};

struct BinTreeNode *initBinTreeNode(char *data);
void visit(char *data);
void preorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);
void postorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);
void inorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);

int main(void)
{
    struct BinTreeNode *root, *parent1, *parent2;

    /* growing the tree */

    root = initBinTreeNode("ECP1026");
    root->left = initBinTreeNode("Kuhan");
    root->right = initBinTreeNode("Lim");

    parent1 = root->left;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("HOSSAIN");
    parent1 = root->left->left;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("PONG KAI SUN");
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode(NULL);

    parent1 = root->left;
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode("LEE JIA WEI");
    parent1 = root->left->right;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("SHEIKH AHNAF");

    parent1 = root->left->right->left;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("FAIZA");
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode(NULL);

    parent1 = root->left->right;
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode("NG CHEA YEAT");

    parent1 = root->left->right->right;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("HI CHIA LING");

    parent1 = root->left->right->right->left;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("PHUAH CHEE HAOU");
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode("MOSTAFA ARABY");

    parent1 = root->left->right->right;
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode("TONG JUN YANG");
    parent1->right->left = initBinTreeNode(NULL);
    parent1->right->right = initBinTreeNode("ANG QIZHENG");

    parent1 = root->left->right->right->right->right;
    parent1->left = initBinTreeNode("DARWIN KUMAR");
    parent1->left->left = initBinTreeNode("HAIZUN NAJWA");
    parent1->left->right = initBinTreeNode("NG XUE NIE");
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode(NULL);

    parent2 = root->right;
    parent2->left = initBinTreeNode("ALMARHOON");
    parent2->left->left = initBinTreeNode("HEMAN RAO");
    parent2->left->right = initBinTreeNode("SOHEIL PRAKASAN SUPPAN");
    parent2->right = initBinTreeNode("GAN WEI TONG");
    parent2->right->left = initBinTreeNode("KEVIN THAM");
    parent2->right->left->left = initBinTreeNode("LIM CHER AIK");
    parent2->right->left->right = initBinTreeNode("TAN WEI XIANG");
    parent2->right->right = initBinTreeNode("WONG HONG WEI");
    parent2->right->right->left = initBinTreeNode("CHEAH KOK YEW");
    parent2->right->right->right = initBinTreeNode("SHIVAA RUTRAN");

    /* traverse and print tree */

    printf("nPreorder traversal:t");
    preorder(root);

    printf("nInorder traversal:t");
    inorder(root);

    printf("nPostorder traversal:t");
    postorder(root);

    return(0);
}

void preorder(struct BinTreeNode *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        /* if Node exists */
        visit(node->data);
        preorder(node->left);
        preorder(node->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct BinTreeNode *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        postorder(node->left);
        postorder(node->right);
        visit(node->data);
    }
}

void inorder(struct BinTreeNode *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        inorder(node->left);
        visit(node->data);
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}

void visit(char *data)
{
    printf("%s\n", data);
}

struct BinTreeNode *initBinTreeNode(char *data)
{
    struct BinTreeNode *temp;

    temp = (struct BinTreeNode *)
           malloc(sizeof(struct BinTreeNode));

    temp->data = data;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->left = NULL;

    return(temp);
}
```

Try to improve this code by adding other data instead of only the name eg. student ID.

Comment: If this code works and you're seeking advice on how to improve it, you should really be asking on [Code Review](https:///codereview.stackexchange.com/).  If there's a problem with this code, you need to ask about that.  You say you want to add a student ID — what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Note that in C (as opposed to C++), the structure definition `struct BinTreeNode { char *data; struct BinTreeNode *left; struct BinTreeNode *right; };` does not define a type `BinTreeNode`.  You need to add `typedef struct BinTreeNode BinTreeNode;` (or equivalent) to get the simple type name as an alias for the tagged structure.

Comment: ... though using the the `struct` keyword and the tag (`struct BinTreeNode`) everywhere, as you appear to be doing, is fine too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger — oops; somewhere I thought I saw a plain `BinTreeNode` (without the `struct`), but I can't see it half an hour or so later.  My comment, although accurate, is superfluous.